# Javascript unable to extract value of text field in Table

Tags: javascript, textfield

I have a table that has n number of rows and the 8th and the 9th cells are editable test fields. I need to extract the value of these fields using Javascript and HTML DOM. I have tried different methods but whenever I alert it I get &nbsp or nothing at all as the alert content.

Following is the creation statements:

```
//Input Fields
for(var i=1; i<=mmrows.length-3; i++)
{//mmrows is the source
    var input1 =document.createElement('input');
    var input2 =document.createElement('input');
    input1.setAttribute("type", "Text");
    input2.setAttribute("type", "Text");
    //input1.id='Inp1'.concat(i);// Tried to assign ID dynamically
    //input2.id='Inp2'.concat(i);
    input1.id='Inp1';
    input2.id='Inp2';
    input1.onkeypress=function(){
        return isNumberKey(arguments[0]);
    }//for validation

    var t1=document.createElement("td");
    t1.appendChild(input1);
    valrows[i+1].cells[8].appendChild(t1);  
    var t2=document.createElement("td");
    t2.appendChild(input2);

    valrows[i+1].cells[9].appendChild(t2);  
}
```

I am trying to extract the values in another function and tried the following:

```
var cells=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
alert(cells.length);
alert(cells[8].innerText);
alert(cells[8].innerHTML);

alert(trim(valrows[i].cells[8].innerHTML));
alert(trim(valrows[i].cells[9].innerHTML));

var str='Inp1'.concat(i);
var str1='Inp2'.concat(i);
alert(document.getElementsById(str).value); //Dynamic ID
alert(document.getElementsById(str1).value);

var tblcells = valrows[i].cells; 
alert(tblcells);
for(var j=0; j<tblcells.length; j++)
{
    alert(tblcells[j].firstElementChild.value);
} ​
```

Please tell me what change I need to make inorder to get the text field value.

Comment: Is there any reasonable explanation as to why you don't use jQuery?

Comment: My development is javascript as we are using an SPM tool in conjunction with this JS code...

Comment: jsFiddle ? Or try http://codepen.io/ "New Pen"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this! Actually it was a mistake by myself; i tried accessing the text values by saying getElement(s)ById - no s required.

so i was able to assign 'id's to these text cells dynamically by using the loop variable i and accessing it by getElementById in a similar loop.

Thanks!